# Formatting issues with Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, sass, formatting

I have been experiencing a recent issue with formatting in .scss, .css and .html files in Visual Studio Code and I can't seem to figure out how to return it to my preferred setting.

Before, I could type a class name, open the bracket and click enter and it would be formatted nicely as shown below. Now when clicking enter, it just drops to a new line and I have to manually create more space and indenting.

**Before**

```
.test {
    |
}
```

**After**

```
.test {
|}
```

### settings.json configuration

```
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Moonlight II Italic",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "svelte.language-server.runtime": "/usr/local/bin/node",
    "npm.keybindingsChangedWarningShown": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "editor.language.brackets": [],
    "[scss]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html": "twig"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "twig": "html"
    },
    "editor.formatOnType": true
}
```

Any help to fix these formatting issues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create snippets of your own ,
and for that you can check this https://youtu.be/wxckctXHSC0

or

you can try resetting your preferences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).